# Grouping Multiple columns and sum of count in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, aggregate

i have a table in pandas df

```
 master_id    pidx   pidy   flag   count
    xxx        a      b       A      10
    xxx        a      c       A      20
    xxx        a      d       A      30
    xxx        b      d       A      40
    xxx        a      c       C      50
    xxx        a      c       C      60
    xxx        x      y       C      70
    xxx        x      y       C      80
```

i want to do a grouping on multiple columns and summing the count irrespective  of flag.

i.e

```
 xxx  a    c   A   20
 xxx  a    c   C   50
 xxx  a    c   C   60
```

final output should be

```
 xxx  a   c   A  130
```

final table should be

```
 master_id   pidx   pidy   flag   count
    xxx        a      b       A      10
    xxx        a      c       A      130
    xxx        a      d       A      30
    xxx        b      d       A      40
    xxx        x      y       C      150
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) - column `flag` is aggregate by `first` and column `count` by `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby(['pidx','pidy']).agg({'flag':'first', 'count':'sum'}).reset_index()
print (df)
  pidx pidy  count flag
0    a    b     10    A
1    a    c    130    A
2    a    d     30    A
3    b    d     40    A
4    x    y    150    C
```

because if use `groupby` by `pidx`, `pidy` and `flag`, output is different:

```
df = df.groupby(['pidx','pidy','flag'], as_index=False)['count'].sum()
print (df)
  pidx pidy flag  count
0    a    b    A     10
1    a    c    A     20
2    a    c    C    110
3    a    d    A     30
4    b    d    A     40
5    x    y    C    150
```

Comment: your code works, but say i have one more column say master_id, then i can't add that column in `df.groupby(['master_id','pidx','pidy'])`  See i edited my df with another column.

Comment: i put leafID inside agg function and it seems to work , `df = df.groupby(['pidx','pidy']).agg({'leafId':'first','flag':'first', 'count':'sum'}).reset_index()`  but is it the right way?

Comment: It depends what do you need. If need group by columns pydx and pidy and get first row of column leafId and flag, and sum all rows in column count youare right.

Comment: I think the best is test it by change values in leafId and flag in small sample of data and test it if need it. (Sorry now I am home only on phone, so not easy answer.)

Comment: no worries, i'll keep trying. suggest  answer only when possible :)   thanks

Comment: I think the best for testing is this sample `print (pd.DataFrame({'count': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80], 'master_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'pidy': ['b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'y', 'y'], 'pidx': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'x', 'x'], 'flag': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']}))` - is `df = df.groupby(['pidx','pidy']).agg({'master_id':'first','flag':'fi‌​rst', 'count':'sum'}).reset_index()` what need?

Comment: i just wanted to add 'master_id' column in my result and i did not knew about .agg , so i just tested it by adding inside the .agg